# How to prove the sequence $(-1)^n$ has no limit using first principles?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $( (-1)^n )$ has no limit, probably by contradiction.

I picked $\epsilon = 1$ and

$$| (-1)^n - \ell | < 1$$

But I don't know what is the best $N$ to get my contradiction.

I only want to use $\epsilon-N$ argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider two cases, based on $\ell \ge 0$ and $\ell < 0$. If $\ell \ge 0$ and $n$ is odd, then

$$\left|(-1)^n - \ell\right| = \ell + 1 \nless 1 = \epsilon$$

Comment: How do you justify the first equality?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then both $(-1)^n$ and $\ell$ are negative, so $(-1)^n - \ell$ is negative. Taking the absolute value flips the sign.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose to the contrary that $(−1)^n\rightarrow L$. Then given $\varepsilon$, there is some $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $|(−1)^n−L|≤\varepsilon$. If $n$ is even, so $|1−L|\le \varepsilon$, if $n$ is odd $|1+L|≤\varepsilon$. Then $2=|1+1|≤|1+L|+|1−L|≤2\varepsilon$. Setting $ε<1$, we get a contradiction.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how we can combine the case for $n$ even and $n$ odd. Why does the logic work? Why can we add $|1-L|$ and $|1+L|$ together?

Comment: It's because you're using the triangle inequality and the fact that all the subsequences convergence to the same limit. There is nothing complicated here. It might be easier to visualize with an extra step, $|1+1|=|(1+L)+(1-L)|$ and after that the triangle inequality and choosing an epsilon small enough. Hopefully, It help you.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know what is the best N to get my contradiction.

I think there is an important misunderstanding here. Recall that if a sequence $(a_n)$ has a limit $\ell$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, **there exists** an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $|a_n-\ell|<\epsilon$.

But you want to prove that that a limit *doesn't* exist. So invert the above conditions. You want to show that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that **for all** $N$, there exists an $n\geq N$ such that $|a_n-\ell|\geq\epsilon$.

So you see, your job is not to choose $N$. On the contrary, you must allow $N$ to take any value! Your job is to choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that for any $N$ and $\ell$ that your adversary may propose, you can find an appropriate lowercase $n$. You were on the right track to start with $\epsilon=1$.

(As it turns out, and as the other answers show, you can choose any $\epsilon\leq1$, and then choose $n=N$ or $n=N+1$ depending on whether $\ell$ is positive and whether $N$ is even.)

Comment: I meant to say what $n$ to choose, is what meant when I say "N". Or I meant to say "pick out" the $N$

Comment: Okay, but that isn't quite right either. It is not enough to choose a single value of $n$. You have to describe $n$ as a function of $\ell$ and $N$. (Or at least prove that it is possible to do so.)